# How to open new div stick to the button of the page using materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

I want new popup window always appear stocked at the bottom right of the page with fixed width/height and overlap the right col if necessary.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karlomn/y5tcnseq/7/):

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6">




      <button href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</button>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer class="page-footer">

</footer>
```

css:

```
.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;

}
```

I tried different tricks with `.box` class but was not successful, so appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want the `.box` class to appear at the bottom, you can try this:

```
.box {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you!